# Parallel RSA encryption in OpenMP

Tags: c, parallel-processing, rsa, openmp

Sometimes my encrypt code is going well, but sometimes it got buffer overflow or did'nt get the right answer when I try to parallel it. I don't know why. This is my code:

```
#ifdef _OPENMP
#pragma omp parallel shared(result)
//#pragma omp parallel for shared(M,C) private(x) schedule(static) default(shared)
#endif
do
{
    mpz_powm(MN, M, N, pub.n);  /* MN = M^N mod n */
    mpz_mul(result, result, MN); /* result = result * MN */
    mpz_mod(result, result, pub.n); /* result = result mod n */
} while(!tmp);

unsigned int i, j;
unsigned int core = (unsigned int) omp_get_num_procs();
for(i = 1; i < core; i++)
{
    if(mpz_get_ui(pub.e) % core == i)
    {
        for(j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            mpz_mul(result, result, M); /* result = result * M */
            mpz_mod(result, result, pub.n); /* result = result mod n */
        }
    }
}

mpz_mod(C, result, pub.n); /* C = result mod n */
```

Comment: You have can run `mpz_powm` in parallel, but the following `mpz_mul` writes `result` in which case you have to synchronize the processes on write.

Comment: how to do that in openmp?

Comment: Oh I got it with #pragma omp critical.

Comment: Well, it would be better to have a temporary variable, so you can compute the multiplication in parallel and then simply copy the multiplication result into the shared variable. I think you will still need to synchronize the processes a second time after the modulo operation. If you have fully working code, please don't forget to answer your own question with it.

Comment: there are a few problems with the posted code:  1) `tmp` not defined and certainly not updated in the `do...while(!tmp);` loop  2) in a (for instance) 4 core CPU, this line: `for(i = 1; i < core; i++)` will only cover 3 of the cores

Comment: this line: `mpz_get_ui(pub.e) % core` will yield results that range from 0 to (core-1)   Probably not quite what you want,

Comment: @user3629249 Can you please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71891372/parallel-execution-of-openmp-got-stuck-after-taking-some-input

Answer (score 1):

It's okay with modify that code to be like this. I can't get the error again. Thank you.

```
#pragma omp parallel shared(result)
do
{
#pragma omp critical
{
    mpz_powm(MN, M, N, pub.n);  
    mpz_mul(result, result, MN); 
    mpz_mod(result, result, pub.n); 
}
} while(!tmp);
```